# Passing Multiple Arguments to main()

Tags: c, parameters, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

For my class I need to create a function that takes in multiple parameters at runtime:

```
void main(int x, int y, int generation, char *layout[20])
```

However when the program runs with my input for these variables the information is not stored and in the debugging process

```
run 3 3 3 Test_Round
print x // returns 5
print y // returns -8779
```

How do I pass multiple arguments into the main function so main will recognize the parameters I give it?

Thanks everyone! I just used argv[1] and so on to get the proper data I need!

Comment: Does your implementation support this type of main function?

Comment: I assume it does since it compiles and only gives warnings.

Comment: You should check the documentation.

Comment: @IlyaMethot That's a bad assumption. The C standard never requires an error. In many cases, wrong code doesn't have to be diagnosed at all; and if it has to be diagnosed, a warning is enough. Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242415/passing-arguments-to-main?rq=1.

Comment: `main` should *always* be defined as `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. If you invoke your program as `my_program 123 456 789`, when main is entered argc will be 4, argv[0] will point to a character array containing "my_program\0", argv[1] will point to a character array containing "123\0", argv[2] will point to a character array containing "456\0", and argv[3] will point to a string containing (you guessed it!) "789\0".

Comment: Ah ok, so in this way I can read the input information and store it into variables.

Answer (score 6):

The standard is clear about how you need to declare your main function.

*From the C99 Standard:*

> ***5.1.2.2.1 Program startup***
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this
>   function. It shall be defined with a **return type** of **int** and with **no
>   parameters**:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> **or** with **two parameters**
>
> (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as
>   they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;9) or in **some
>   other implementation-defined manner**.
>
> **If they are declared, the
>   parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints**:
>
> — The value of `argc` shall be **nonnegative**.
>
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a **null
>   pointer.**
>
> — If the value of `argc` is **greater than zero**, the array
>   members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall **contain pointers**
>   **to strings**, which are given implementation-defined values by the host
>   environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the
>   program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere
>   in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the
>   implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in
>   lowercase.
>
> — If the value of `argc` is **greater than zero**, the string
>   pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be
>   the **null character** if the program name is not available from the host
>   environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
>   pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program
>   parameters.
>
> — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to
>   by the `argv` array shall **be modifiable** by the program, and **retain their
>   last-stored values** between **program startup** and **program termination**.

Comment: I'm a little confused. It seems that any additional arguments are stored somewhere in argv[1].

How do I find the additional parameters and store/use them in variables?

Comment: `the strings pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program parameters.`

Comment: `argv[0] represents the program name`

Answer (score 1):

```
 void main(int x, int y, int generation, char *layout[20])
```

is an invalid signature of `main()`. You need to use

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

where, `argv[0]` to `argv[argc-1]` will hold the parameters passed to `main()`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.2,

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.

Comment: How do I define the arguments that I enter?

Do I reference them using 

    int x;
    argv[0] = x;

and so on?

Comment: argv[0] is the name of the executable, so x = argv[1], y = argv[2], etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass more than two argument in main function. In main function, you can pass only `two` argument or `Zero` argument.

Using following parameters, you can pass the value command line.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: @alk - Thanks for suggest me.

Comment: How do I pass these arguments into the function then and store them?

Comment: Read this link for more information : http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-function/c-command-line-arguments/